# Pyserial: How to write and read list of float

Tags: python, type-conversion, pyserial

I have a list of float:

```
[0, 0, 0.8125, 0.2421875, -0.939453125, 0.60888671875, 0.3944091796875]
```

but `ser.write(...)` and `ser.read(...)` can do with string data

I think I must map a list of float to a string of list of float.

like this:

```
'[0, 0, 0.8125, 0.2421875, -0.939453125, 0.60888671875, 0.3944091796875]'
```

**My Question: What code to map it?**

so now we can write or read this thing, and then it map back to list of float again.

Answer (score 1):

so, you mean convert all the float into string:

```
>>> map(lambda x: str(x), s)
['0', '0', '0.8125', '0.2421875', '-0.939453125', '0.60888671875', '0.394409179688']
>>>
```

OR

```
>>> s = [0, 0, 0.8125, 0.2421875, -0.939453125, 0.60888671875, 0.3944091796875]
>>> string_float = [ str(x) for x in s]
>>> string_float
['0', '0', '0.8125', '0.2421875', '-0.939453125', '0.60888671875', '0.394409179688']
>>>
```

OR if you want to convert the whole list into string:

```
>>> s = [0, 0, 0.8125, 0.2421875, -0.939453125, 0.60888671875, 0.3944091796875]
>>> str(s)
'[0, 0, 0.8125, 0.2421875, -0.939453125, 0.60888671875, 0.3944091796875]'
>>>
```

And to convert back:

```
>>> s = [0, 0, 0.8125, 0.2421875, -0.939453125, 0.60888671875, 0.3944091796875]
>>> type(s)
<type 'list'>
>>> string = str(s)
>>> type(string)
<type 'str'>
>>> import ast
>>> original = ast.literal_eval(string)
>>> type(original)
<type 'list'>
>>> original
[0, 0, 0.8125, 0.2421875, -0.939453125, 0.60888671875, 0.3944091796875]
>>>
```

**Let me know if thats not the answer.**

Comment: never mind, thats why i was trying to solve in different ways :)

Comment: I want to convert the whole list into str :)

Comment: after that, Could you convert that string come back to the whole list again ?

Comment: if that helps, please don't forget to select as answer :)

Comment: If I would like to do this without 'ast' module.
Do you have other way to do this ?
Thanks you :)